# Mod_rewrite on all website images

Tags: performance, http, mod-rewrite

I'm designing an image repository. I want to uncouple the filename from the image html link. For instance:

- image in filesystem is called `images/items/12543.jpg`
- HTML is `<img src="images/car.jpg" />`

Does anyone strongly discourages me to rewrite all image requests using PHP so when retrieving `images/car.jpg`, Apache really replies content from `images/items/12543.jpg`?

I don't know if I may get performance problems.

Comment: Are you asking about mod_rewrite rules or outputting your images via php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may take a long time until you will get actual performance problems with this, but running each request for a resource through PHP (every process, especially when connecting to a database or doing other complex things, taking up considerable memory *on each request*) is a bad idea architecturally IMO.

I would recommend either translating `12543` to `car` in the file system already, and then doing a (cheaper) URL rewrite for it:

```
* images/items/car.jpg
* <img src="images/car.jpg" />
```

Alternative idea: How about doing it like Stack Overflow. Name the jpeg `12543.jpg` and do

```
<img src="images/12543/car.jpg">
```

(The `car` part being arbitrary and there only for the user's and search engines' enjoyment - what is really parsed by the rewrite rule, and used to fetch the image, is only the `12543` and the `.jpg`).